# Hartl's Rails Tutorial Chapter 9 Exercise 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

[Updating, showing, and deleting users, exercises](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/updating-showing-and-deleting-users#sec%3aupdating_deleting_exercises)

Is there a way to create an Rspec test for User controller actions such as "create" and "new?"

I'm not quite clear on the difference between the two actions "create" and "new" themselves either; could someone please be so kind as to elaborate?

After creating the test how would I go about implementing the redirect_to root_path? I think I am supposed to include the "new" and "create" actions in the before_filter signed_in section but this doesn't automatically redirect to the root.

I tried to get the tests to pass by modifying the users_controller.rb file as follows:

```
  def create
    if signed_in?
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      @user = User.new(params[:user])
      if @user.save
        sign_in @user
        flash[:success] = "Welcome to the Sample App!"
        redirect_to @user
      else
        render 'new'
      end
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes; and this is partially begun around [7.16](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/book/ruby-on-rails-tutorial#code%3abasic_signup_tests) and elsewhere.
2. One actually creates a user (`create`). One is for the page *for* creating a new user (`new`).
3. Not sure I understand the question.

Comment: Please see my above edit; hopefully it will provide some clarity. I really appreciate your help. I couldn't comment here before for some reason...

Comment: @user1469059 Still not sure I understand.

Comment: Would modifying the users_controller.rb as shown above redirect signed in users to the root path but work correctly otherwise?

Comment: @user1469059 Might; did you try it?

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't work. I'm not quite sure why. I think my logic is correct but the syntax must be wrong somewhere. When I wrote the test I was using response { specify.should redirect_to(root_path) } and it gave me an ActionDispatch error. I tried looking it up and read somewhere that this had to do with Capybara. I'm not quite sure. Is there some resource where I could read more about the syntax for Rspec and Capybara?

Comment: @user1469059 For both I've always started at the [rspec home](http://rspec.info/) and [capybara home](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara). I learned a lot from the PragProg RSpec book, although I don't know how well it's held up over time. I'm not always sure how to get less-experienced devs up to speed anymore, though, because it's a more intuitive process for me and I can't "un-think" my process and put myself in other shoes, you know? :/

Comment: Yes, I completely understand. I really appreciate your guidance nonetheless. I've been developing front-end for over 15 years but am now finally deciding to delve deeper. Are there any books you would recommend I read based on this limited experience?

I'm not familiar with the standard protocol here but I will mark your answer as accepted even though I haven't figured out how to do the exercise yet. Hopefully I'll be able to figure it out on my own; that's the best way to learn after all :)

Comment: @user1469059 For the Rails end I recommend the Hartl tutorial; it's up-to-date, and complete as far as it goes. It's important to have apidock.com at ready standby. Beyond that... kind of a crap shoot; there aren't too many *horrible* resources, it kind of depends on what you respond best too.

Comment: Thanks, I'll start digging into the docks.

Comment: Thanks, I figured it out. I was using the wrong syntax for Capybara.

Answer (score 10):

I did a before filter for that, seems to work well,
for the test I did this:

on authentication_pages_spec.rb

```
describe "signin" do
  describe "authorization" do
    describe "for signed in users" do
      let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
      let(:new_user) { FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:user) }
      before { sign_in user }

      describe "using a 'new' action" do
        before { get new_user_path }
        specify { response.should redirect_to(root_path) }
      end

      describe "using a 'create' action" do
        before { post users_path new_user }
        specify { response.should redirect_to(root_path) }
      end         
    end
  end
end
```

Like @WillJones says, some people might have to add `no_capybara: true` to the before block

and on my users controller:

```
before_filter :signed_in_user_filter, only: [:new, :create]

def signed_in_user_filter
  redirect_to root_path, notice: "Already logged in" if signed_in?
end
```

For the difference between the new and create actions, it has to do with the [REST](http://old.thoughtsincomputation.com/posts/understanding-rest-in-rails-3) architectural style, but basically, `new` is an action from users controller that responds to a `GET` request and is the one that's in charge of returning the view it responds to (in this case, a new user form). `create` on the other hand, is an action that responds to a `POST` request, it doesn't render anything (it can respond with javascript, but that's an advanced topic) and it's the one responsible for creating new users, like the action's name implies.

Comment: To get mine to work I had to pass `before { sign_in user, no_capybara: true }` and pass `users_path(user)`. Just for others' info!

Comment: @WillJones: Thank you. I stared at it for 45 minutes and your tip on no_capybara: true saved me.

Answer (score 0):

I did a before filter for that too, but my filter is different and I don't understand why it works.

My users controller has following entries

```
   class UsersController < ApplicationController
.
.
  before_filter :logged_in_user, only: [:new, :create]
.
.
def logged_in_user
      redirect_to(root_path) if !current_user?(@user)
  end
```

It works just fine as in **rkrdo**'s example and corresponding tests pass. But does it mean that current_user is not the same as a user when user is signed-in and conversely? In my opinion they should be equal in first case and shouldn't in second.