# Signed-in users have no reason to access the new and create (is there a better answer)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, railstutorial.org

This is the answer to one common question asked by many users and for those who are using Rails 4.0 and following the updated tutorial,

Since answer to this question has been updated with the newer version of **Railstutorial(rails 4.0)** by Michael Hartl's

I have found in almost every post related to this question that the solution to this problem is to add these lines in **users_controller.rb** file

```
before_filter :signed_in_user_filter, only: [:new, :create]

.
.
.
def signed_in_user_filter
    if signed_in?
        redirect_to root_path, notice: "Already logged in"
    end
end
```

but this solution only works for **localhost:3000/signup** but will not do anything to **localhost:3000/signin** since its the solution given with respect to railstutorial(Rails 3.0).And its not going to work for those who are following Railstutorial(Rails 4.0).

For referrence to this question you can see this post [Railstutorial:exercise 9.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11118680/hartls-rails-tutorial-chapter-9-exercise-6?lq=1/)

Comment: Please format the question to look like a question and post the answer as an answer. See [Etiquette for answering your own question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question) for more instructions.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the proper format.I just wanted to help other users those who are using rails 4.0 and have faced the same problem but due to lack of updation of answer they didn't able to find the answer.anyways thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So,for Rails 4.0, I have found solution to this while looking at the **/config/routes.rb** file

```
match '/signup',  to: 'users#new',            via: 'get' 
  match '/signin',  to: 'sessions#new',         via: 'get'
```

Those who are using Rails 4.0 and following the tutorial, you need to edit "new" method in **users_controller.rb** file for restricting the access to **/signup** path( when user is already logged-in) and "new" method in **sessions_controller.rb** file for restricting the access to **/signin** path when already logged-in.

You need to add these lines to "new" method in **users_controller.rb** file

```
def new
  if signed_in?
   redirect_to root_url
   flash[:notify] = '!Please log-out before Signing-up'
   else
   @user = User.new
  end
end
```

And add these lines to "new" method in **sessions_controller.rb** file

```
def new
   if signed_in?
    redirect_to root_url
    flash[:error] = 'Already logged-in'
   else
   end
  end
```

This solution has worked for me, as i am also using Rails 4.0(railstutorials)